# Hashing error with crossroads.js

Tags: javascript, url-routing

I'm testing out [crossroads.js](https://github.com/millermedeiros/crossroads.js) and [hasher.js](https://github.com/millermedeiros/Hasher) together and the following code errors on the second setHash call, with "Function.prototype.apply: argument is not an Object".  This is both in IE and Chrome.

```
crossroads.addRoute( 'lorem/{id}', function( id ) { alert( id ); } );

hasher.changed.add( crossroads.parse, crossroads );
hasher.init();

hasher.setHash('lorem/123');  // works with alert(123)
hasher.setHash('lorem/456');  // javascript error
```

Am I doing something wrong here?  The first setHash shows the alert fine.

Comment: what has the browser got to do with it, isn't this a Node.js thing? or am I somehow missing the question?

Comment: I'm not using Node.js, it's just a bit of test code running in the browser.  The only javascript libraries included are signals.min.js, crossroads.min.js and hasher.min.js.  So as far as I understand it shouldn't do anything except change the URL's hash twice, showing a couple of alerts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I worked out what the problem is.  The `crossroads.parse` has the wrong signature (request, defaultArgs) for the `hasher.changed` signal and shouldn't be added directly with this code: `hasher.changed.add(crossroads.parse, crossroads)`.  If I pass in a proxy method with signature (newHash, oldHash) it works:

```
crossroads.addRoute( 'lorem/{id}', function( id ) { alert( id ); } );
var proxy = function( newHash, oldHash ) { crossroads.parse( newHash ); };

hasher.changed.add( proxy );  // Use to be hasher.changed.add( crossroads.parse, crossroads );
hasher.init();

hasher.setHash('lorem/123');
hasher.setHash('lorem/456');
```

The reason it works the first time is because there's no `oldHash` and so no `defaultArgs`.  And `defaultArgs` gets initialised to an empty array at the beginning of the `parse` method if it's blank.

But this works a little too well because now I'm now getting two alerts for each `setHash` call.

Comment: Perfect this also solves a problem where the call back for crossroads.routed.add was being passed (oldroute,newroute) instead of (route, data)